# postgresql where clause behavior

Tags: postgresql

I made two queries that I thought should have the same result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id1) id1, value 
    FROM (
        SELECT table1.id1, table2.value 
            FROM table1 
            JOIN table2 ON table1.id1=table2.id 
            WHERE table2.value = '1') 
    AS result1 ORDER BY id1) 
AS result2;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id1) id1, value 
    FROM (
        SELECT table1.id1, table2.value 
        FROM table1 
        JOIN table2 ON table1.id1=table2.id 
    ) 
    AS result1 ORDER BY id1) 
AS result2
WHERE value = '1';
```

The only difference being that one had the WHERE clause inside SELECT DISTINCT ON, and the other outside that, but inside SELECT COUNT. But the results were not the same. I don't understand why the position of the WHERE clause should make a difference in this case. Can anyone explain? Or is there a better way to phrase this question?

Comment: even your original badly formated post had `AS result2 WHERE table2.value = '1';` in the second query which doesn't match with your description: The only difference being that one had the WHERE clause inside SELECT DISTINCT ON, and the other outside that, but inside SELECT COUNT. Could you please fix your queries?

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking me to fix the queries. If I knew what was wrong with them I wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: Your second query has a `WHERE` clause, but the first does not.  Therefore, they will have different results.

Comment: If you look more closely you will see that they both have a WHERE clause. My question is why does the position of the WHERE make a difference.

Comment: @user1625423 because those queries just do not work. `select distinct`  refers to `table1`, `table2` but `table1` and `table2` do not exists -- the table name is `result1`. Second query is broken in the same way. Moreover, `table2` (in `WHERE table2.value = '1';`) does not exist and it should be referenced as `result2`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me fix my typos and formatting, Ondrej.

Comment: So nobody knows how to answer this question?

Comment: Can you post data needed to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

here's a good way to look at this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, value
  FROM (select 1 as id, 1 as value
        union
        select 1 as id, 2 as value) a;

SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, value
  FROM (select 1 as id, 1 as value
        union
        select 1 as id, 2 as value) a
 WHERE value = 2;
```

The problem has to do with the unique conditions and what is visible where.  It is behavior by design.